# Auth0: is it possible to disallow password-based login for a single user?

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-connection

My app is using email addresses as unique identifiers for users. It also allows users to log in via social connections, i.e. Google Oauth. I want to disable password-based login when a user logs in with Google. Is it possible to somehow configure this in Auth0? I'd need to do it on both the login page, as well as on Auth0's authorization server.

(Note that I want to do this dynamically, on a per-user basis, rather than globally disable database connections.)

Or, more generally, is there a generalized way to control "which methods of auth should be available for a specific user"?

Comment: In Auth0 portal go to `Authentication -> Database -> <Your Connection Name> -> Turn on Disable Sign Ups`